# Pass SelectList item list one controller to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

I had used select list item in controller action and pass the select list item values to another controller action by passing in parameter but didn't get any values in another controller action

// first controller action

```
List<SelectListItem> dropdownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)singlecheckbox)
  {
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(item);
    dropdownItems.AddRange(new[]{
    new SelectListItem() { Text = null, Value = Id.ToString() }});
  }
 return RedirectToAction("mergeletterttofiles123", "managefile", new { dropdownItems, SeatId = seatId });
```

// 2nd controller action

```
public ActionResult mergeletterttofiles123(List<SelectListItem> dropdownItems, int SeatId, string msg)
{
     // dropdownItems shows null( 0 count)
}
```

Comment: You cant pass complex objects (unless they contain only value types) or collections as a parameter to an `ActionResult` GET method. You need to persist the collection somewhere are get it again (although it your case, just generate the `SelectList` again in the second method.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can store list in Session:

```
...........
//your code
Session["dropdownItems"]=dropdownItems;
RedirectToAction("mergeletterttofiles123", "managefile", new { SeatId = seatId });
```

And then:

```
public ActionResult mergeletterttofiles123(int SeatId, string msg)
{
    //then get it using something like
    var dropdownItems = Session["dropdownItems"] as List<SelectListItem>;
}
```